# Signal R Thread blocking the HTTP Request and Response

Tags: objective-c, signalr

I am facing problem with Signal R Thread blocking the HTTP Request and Response.
Application is going to freeze while http getting the response because Signal R Polling is always running.

Please suggest.

Comment: how about use different port for signalr?

Comment: @KennethLi How to change the port for signal r while I am using same server instance.

Comment: You should have a signalr Server in the form of console or Winform or Windows Services

Comment: Server team not able to change the port, because server have single port to communication with application. Our api's and signal both are using same instance. Is it possible to create different thread to call signal r and different thread for api url request, if yes how can we implement?

Comment: I believe you cannot use the same port, even if you can, it can't be a good practice!  I had similar case before, I had some clients that can call a webservices in Server X, and also those clients can call signalr Server in Server Y.  If X and Y use the same port, I removed the call to Server X from the clients' code, so that clients only call Server Y by  signalr, then have Server Y calls the Server X webservices.  Of course, in your case Server X and Server Y can be the same Server.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to use the same instance?  because in my codes I always try to 'separate' codes so that when my number of clients grow, I can buy more servers.  e.g. only for sql, two for webapi, one for signalr server.

Comment: Can we run SignalR asynchronously?